# Img src only changing once through javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Alright so im building a voting system on my blog. Much like the one here on stackoverflow. The system works fine on the first post of the blog roll, but every other post the images aren't changing when they are clicked, however the actually voting process is still being carried out.

Why is that? Any help would be great!

Here is my JS:

```
function upvote(id)
  {
    sender = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(document.getElementById("upvoteimg").src.indexOf("voted") == -1)  //have they already voted up?
    {
      document.getElementById("upvoteimg").src = "assets/upvoted.png"; // change to upvoted
      sender.open("GET","/like/index/" + id ,true);
      sender.send();
      document.getElementById("likes").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("likes").innerHTML) +1; //update #
    }
  else
    {
      document.getElementById("upvoteimg").src = "assets/upvote.png"; //change to not upvoted
      sender.open("GET","/like/index/" + id ,true);
      sender.send()
      document.getElementById("likes").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("likes").innerHTML) - 1; //update #
    }

  }

  function downvote(id)
  {
    sender = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(document.getElementById("downvoteimg").src.indexOf("voted") == -1) //have they already downvoted?
    {
      document.getElementById("downvoteimg").src = "assets/downvoted.png"; //change to downvoted
      sender.open("GET","/like/down/" + id ,true);
      sender.send()
      document.getElementById("likes").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("likes").innerHTML) - 1; //update #
    }
  else
    {
      document.getElementById("downvoteimg").src = "assets/downvote.png"; //change to not downvoted
      sender.open("GET","/like/down/" + id ,true);
      sender.send()
      document.getElementById("likes").innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById("likes").innerHTML) +1; //update #
    }
  }
```

And here are the buttons in my view:

```
<!-- Voting System -->
<div id="post-vote">
    <% #DownVote %>
        <%if user_signed_in?%>  
            <%if Dislikes.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :article_id =>a.id).size == 0%>
                <%= image_tag("downvote.png", "onclick" => "downvote(#{a.id})", "id" => "downvoteimg") %>
            <%else%>
                <%= image_tag("downvoted.png", "onclick" => "downvote(#{a.id})", "id" => "downvoteimg") %>
            <%end%>
        <%else%>
            <%= image_tag("downvote.png", "onclick" => "alert('You must login to vote.')", "id" => "downvoteimg") %>
        <%end%>
    <% #TheNumber %>
    <span id="likes" class="vote-count"><%= a.likes.size - Dislikes.where(:article_id =>a.id).size%></span>

    <% #UpVote %>
        <%if user_signed_in?%>  
            <%if !a.likes.include?(current_user)%>
                <%= image_tag("upvote.png",  "id" => "upvoteimg", "onclick" => "upvote(#{a.id})") %>
            <%else%>
                <%= image_tag("upvoted.png",  "id" => "upvoteimg", "onclick" => "upvote(#{a.id})") %>
            <%end%>
        <%else%>
            <%= image_tag("upvote.png", "id" => "upvoteimg", "onclick" => "alert('You must login to vote.')") %>
        <%end%>
</div>
```

Comment: Your IDs must be unique. Switch to classes instead, and you should be sorted.

Comment: @jamwaffles can you show how to go about that?

Comment: @Deekor Instead of `id=` use `class=` if you're handling a group of HTML elements.

Comment: @david I dont want to change all the images on the page. Just the ones pertaining to the single post they voted on.

Comment: Are there many up & down arrows (i.e. blog posts you can vote on) at the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed all the images in the js to have and unique id `document.getElementById("upvoteimg")` to `document.getElementById("upvoteimg" + id)`

and all the images in the view to `<%= image_tag("downvoted.png", "onclick" => "downvote(#{a.id})", "id" => "downvoteimg#{a.id}") %>`